# How to move table row to the top within a loop - React

Tags: java, reactjs, html-table, components

I have a loop which goes through an array (*files*) of objects (*person*). If the person works as a doctor or a vet I would like to display their row at the top of the table, if not, they should be displayed under the doctors and vets. I have a sample piece of code as to where i believe the code should be (See: `<PLACE AT TOP OF TABLE>`). I've been over and back with solutions and can't get anything solid. I have tried to add these *person*s to an array, add them to a new table component and insert the table here but no avail. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
<tbody>
{props.files.map(person=> ( 
    <div>
        {(person.job === "doctor" || person.job === "vet") ? <PLACE AT TOP OF TABLE> :
            <tr>
                <td>{person.name}</td>
                <td>{person.age}</td>
                <td>{person.job}</td>
            </tr>
         }
    </div>
))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Sort `props.files` based on your custom sort logic before rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different loops, the first loop, which searches for a doctor or a vet, occurs at the top of a table, then the second loop shows the others except the doctors and the vets